# f-string padding issue with idle

Tags: python, macos, padding, python-idle, f-string

i was printing some simple text and after a while the padding got funky

i have tried changing the text size and font in idle to no avail
i have also tried running it in the terminal which did print the text correct

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(_folder):
        for folder in dirs:
            
            if(folder!="in use"):
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(_folder+"in use/"):
                    if any(folder in word for word in files):
                        print(f'{folder:<25} (active)')
                    else:
                        print(f'{folder:<25} (unactive)')

> fox                       (active)
> mix                       (active)
> neko                      (active)
```

when copy pasting the result i now noticed that it does line up but in the idle shell i looks like [idle shell result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpFEp.png)

Comment: Well, it looks that in idle shell you aren't using fixed-size font. So the padding isn't working properly.